# How to add a scrollbar for a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am new to `angular js`. I have `dropdown` in which more than 20 elements are there. The list will go on increasing. So, I want to have a scrollbar for this. I have tried different ways, used `size` attribute to `select`  and `overflow` but no luck. My code is like -

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="domain">Domain</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <div class="multiselect">
                                <div class="selectBox" ng-click="showCheckboxes()">
                                  <select>
                                        <option>Select an option</option>
                                   </select>
                                     <div class="overSelect"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="checkboxes" >
                                    <label  ng-repeat="domain in allDomainValues" for="{{domain.name}}">
                                        <input type="checkbox" value={{domain.name}} ng-click="getthecheckeddomains(domain.name)" ng-disabled="isalreadychecked" id="{{domain.name}} " />{{domain.name}}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

css -

```
.multiselect {
  width: 169px;
}

.selectBox {
  position: relative;
}

.selectBox select {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.overSelect {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#checkboxes {
  display: none;
  border: 1px #dadada solid;
}

#checkboxes label {
  display: block;
}

#checkboxes label:hover {
  background-color: #1e90ff;
}
```

In controller -

```
var expand  = false
$scope.allDomainValues = [{ name: 'HR' }, { name: 'Finance' }, { name: 'Banking' }, { name: 'Telecom' }];
$scope.showCheckboxes = function() {
                    var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
                    if (!expand) {
                    checkboxes.style.display = "block";
                    expand = true;
                    } else {
                    checkboxes.style.display = "none";
                    expand = false;
                    }
                };
```

How to resolve this ? Any help will be great for me.

Comment: there's no way you can add *scrollbar* to the default dropdown/select tag, you need to use custom plugin like **chosen** in *AngularJS* for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
    .dropdown-menu{
       max-height: 300px;
       overflow-y: auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

<div ng-controller="DropdownCtrl">


    <!-- Single button -->
    <div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" ng-disabled="disabled">
        Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li ng-repeat="item in items"><a href="#">{{item}}</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>


</div>
  </body>
</html>


Javascript :
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

function DropdownCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.items = [];

  for(i=0; i<100; i++){
    $scope.items.push("val_" + i);
  }





  $scope.status = {
    isopen: false
  };

  $scope.toggled = function(open) {
    console.log('Dropdown is now: ', open);
  };

  $scope.toggleDropdown = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope.status.isopen = !$scope.status.isopen;
  };
}
```

Comment: Please try the above solution . Plunkr Link - http://plnkr.co/edit/0ppCye?p=preview